# WP_Query sort category by term

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I'm looking to make the code below sort my custom posttype (Product Type).
So that my active page will only show the posts with the term 'Oil', rather then 'Fuel' and 'Tires'.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'Products',
  'posts_per_page' => -1
);

$my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
  while($my_query->have_posts() ) {                           
    echo '<div class="custom-post">';
    $my_query->the_post();
    echo '<p>' . the_content() . '</p>';
    the_post_thumbnail();
    echo '</div>';
  }
  wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

// Edit, as a reply to the 3 below answers

I assume the foreach loop is a replacement for the WP_Query method, but the tax_query was new to me, and now that I know it exists I looked it up in the codex, however it still wont work. I honostly believe it is something as simple as me naming something in the tax_query wrongly, so I will show my taxonomy code here:

```
function my_custom_taxonomies() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'product-type',
        'products',
        array(
            'label' => 'Type of Product',
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'race-products' ),
            'hierarchical' => true,
        )
    );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_taxonomies' );
```

And the change to the $args:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'Products',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array( 
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product-type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'oil'
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
<?php
    $myposts = get_posts(array(
        'showposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'Products',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'products_cat',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'oil'
               );
        )
     )
    );

    foreach ($myposts as $mypost) {
          echo $mypost->post_title . '<br/>';
          echo $mypost->post_content . '<br/>';
          echo  get_the_post_thumbnail( $mypost->ID );
    }
?>
```

Comment: Fixed it, it was just me mixing my mother-tongue 'Olie' with 'Oil', thanks so much for the tax_query info! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_type' => 'product_type',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'id',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your_texonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'Oil',
        ),
    ),));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try the following parameters in query.

```
$args = array(
 'post_status' = 'publish',
 'tax_query' = array(
     'taxonomy' => 'categories',
     'field'    => 'id',
     'term'     =>  'category id here'
 )
);
$the_query = wp_query($args);
```

Comment: post_status and tax_query are missing the arrow. Example:

'post_status' => 'publish',